# execute a query using entity manager

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

I have a query to get the size of databases I have.
I have written the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Long> results = (List<Long>) em.createQuery("SELECT sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 \"DataBaseSizeinMB\" FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema ").getResultList();
```

where `em` is the `EntityManager`. The query on its own runs successfully in `phpadmin`. But when I run it in my `java` code, I get `exception`.

**EDIT:**
The answer is this:

```
List<Object> list = (List<Object>) em.createNativeQuery(
         "SELECT sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema "
).getResultList();


for (Object record : list) {
    double sum = (double) Double.parseDouble(record.toString());
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: add `StackTrace` Please ..  :)

Comment: the trace is there now.

Answer (score 3):

It works on phpmyadmin because it's a native query. Try using `em.createNativeQuery()`. That method should be used for plain SQL queries. `em.createQuery()` accept queries written in JPQL (Java Persistence Query Language).

Docs of `createNativeQuery(String sqlString)`:

> @param sqlString a native SQL query string

Docs of `createQuery(String qlString)`:

> @param qlString a Java Persistence query string

Answer (score 0):

It probably the \"DataBaseSizeinMB\"

Try to remove this.

Additionally you should always post the Stack Trace here